# Does anyone have any idea, why I get this error or how I can improve the code: nohup: can't execute 'create_directory.sh': No such file or directory

Tags: linux, shell

**can't execute 'create_directory.sh': No such file or directory**
I got the error above. I ran it with nohup filename.sh &
Does anyone know how I can solve it?

```
. /usr/local/bin/orasetenv
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/bin

#############################################################
# 1. Variables for Directory Name 
#############################################################

PN="test"
LG="log"

#############################################################
# 2. Change Directory
#############################################################

cd /folder/subfolder


#############################################################
# 3. Make Directory
#############################################################

mkdir -m 777 $PN

cd /folder/subfolder/$PN

mkdir -m 777 $LG

#############################################################
# 3. Change Directory & Make Directories
#############################################################

cd /folder/subfolder/$PN

mkdir -m 777 yes1
mkdir -m 777 yes2
mkdir -m 777 yes3
mkdir -m 777 yes4
ln -s ../log /folder/subfolder/$PN/log
ln -s /folder/otherfolder/subfolder /folder/subfolder/$PN/otherfolder



#############################################################
# Ende / Exit
##############################################################

exit
```

**can't execute 'create_directory.sh': No such file or directory**
I got the error above. I ran it with nohup filename.sh &
Does anyone know how I can solve it?

Comment: I don't see `create_directory.sh` anywhere in the script.

Comment: The script should begin with `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script. Then you'll see a transcript of the commands it's executing, so you can see which command produces that error. It might be in the `orasetenv` script.

Comment: assuming you actually meant you ran `nohup create_directory.sh &`, the problem is that `.` is not in your path. Try `nohup ./create_directory.sh &` or `nohup /full/path/to/create_directory.sh &`

Answer (score 0):

1. Before executing `cd /folder/subfolder` command; you required to create it with absolute path. e.g. `mkdir -p /folder/subfolder`.
2. The PATH variable used in the command `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/bin` interferes with system-wide PATH variable. So, its better to choose some other name e.g. `export MY_DIR=/opt/bin`.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   export MY_DIR=/opt/bin

   PN="test"
   LG="log"

   mkdir -p "$MY_DIR/folder/subfolder" "$MY_DIR/folder/otherfolder/subfolder"
   cd $MY_DIR

   mkdir -m 777 $PN

   cd $MY_DIR/$PN

   mkdir -m 777 $LG

   mkdir -m 777 yes1
   mkdir -m 777 yes2
   mkdir -m 777 yes3
   mkdir -m 777 yes4
   ln -s ../log $MY_DIR/$PN/log
   ln -s /folder/otherfolder/subfolder $MY_DIR/$PN/otherfolder
   ```